# Accessing a multidimensional array (that is stored in $_SESSION) using foreach. gives warning

Tags: php, arrays, session, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a multidimensional array $_SESSION("cart"), when I print it recursively, it gives:

```
array

[0] => Array
    (
        [type] => Side orders
        [name] => French Fries
        [choice] => small
        [quantity] => 1
        [price] => 225
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [type] => Specialty Pizzas
        [name] => Vegetarian
        [choice] => large
        [quantity] => 1
        [price] => 1580
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [type] => Specialty Pizzas
        [name] => Mediterranean
        [choice] => large
        [quantity] => 1
        [price] => 1580
    )
```

)
I am trying to print the cart by looping through the array of arrays (keys:1,2,3...) and have direct access to [type, name, choice...]
however when I try to access it using the following code:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["cart"]) && count($_SESSION["cart"])>0)
{
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r ($_SESSION["cart"]);
            echo '</pre>';
            foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $key->$item){

                $ty = $item->type;
                $nm = $item->name;
                $ch = $item->choice;
                $pr = $item->price;
                $qt = $item->quantity;
                ?>  

                <li>

                    <?= $ty ?>
                    <?= $nm ?>
                    <?= $ch ?>
                    <?= $pr ?>
                    <?= $qt ?>

}}
```

this gives a warning and fatal error:
        Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in ... on line 15 (the line that contains      foreach loop)

Warning: Creating default object from empty value in ... line 14
Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in ...on line 14

I tried to set key=0 before the loop and increment it in the loop; and iterate the key but it didnt seem like a valid solution because it was not printing the values, but the fatal error was gone. I am not sure what is wrong.

me error reporting is
       error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in:

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $key->$item) {
```

to:

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $key => $item) {
```

The `foreach` statement have two structures:

```
1. foreach ($array as $value)
2. foreach ($array as $key => $value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests the problem very well.

First,

`foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $key->$item) {` this is incorrect. Use `$key => $item`.

Also,

`$item->type;` - this is how you access properties of an *object* (not an array).

`$item['type'];` - this is what you want instead.